# Error linking button

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.3, uialertview, alert

I've been trying to get this right all day and has finally only got one error 
heres a image.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alertView` is still missing a brace.

Also, you do not use `()` at `showAlert`'s declaration.

May I suggest you tab appropriately so it is much easier to see missing braces. It'll help you in the long run. Furthermore, the code itself posted instead of an image is even more helpful, then we could just copy/paste to edit it ourselves.

**Edit**

Here's what it should look like, properly formatted. Also I believe the delegate should be set to `self` instead of `nil` in this case, so I made that correct.

You should adopt a programming style that lets you easily see things like missing braces. If any braces were missing from below, it would be pretty obvious because of the tabbing style.

```
-(void)showAlert 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"hello"
                                                    message:@"what's your name"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"apple", @"google", @"yahoo", nil];
    [alert show];
}   

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //...
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        //...
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 3)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Picm still have the `()`, `alertView():` is wrong. Like I said, no `()` for declarations. Furthermore, you do not have an ending brace of the previous method, there should be a `}` after `[alert show];`.

Comment: sorry about this I'm pretty new and what about now

Comment: @Picm there, you go, that is what you should have.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the brace of the method before the error (showAlert).

Comment: please can you check out my question I've edited do you no what went wrong??

Comment: You read my answer at all? The error is that you didn't **close** the **brace** and not that you didn't **open** the **bracket**...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your terminating curly brace for showAlert().

Comment: please can you check out my question I've edited do you no what went wrong??

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) showAlert {

}   

 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


}
```